# Conditions for the iterative method to work

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us say that I would like to solve the following differential equation iteratively:
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=g(x)f(x)$$
with $f(x_{0})=1$. Meaning, that I first integrate,
$$f(x)=1+\int_{x_{0}}^{x}dx^{\prime}\,g(x^{\prime})f(x^{\prime})$$
and then I repeatedly substitute:
$$f(x)=1+\int_{x_{0}}^{x}dx^{\prime}\,g(x^{\prime})\left[1+\int_{x_{0}}^{x^{\prime}}dx^{\prime\prime}\,g(x^{\prime\prime})f(x^{\prime\prime})\right]$$
what are the conditions that $g(x)$ has to satisfy for this method to be valid?

Comment: a good condition would be $g$ measurable, but usually we don't define such problems without imposing $f \in C^1$ so $g$ should be continuous

Comment: @Gonçalo: It is not a simple exponent as you wrote but rather some "ordered" exponent in which every iteration is integrated over a different interval. Let me ask my question differently - for $g$ given by a distribution this method with fail. What exactly cause that?

Comment: @Gonçalo: The solution that you wrote is obviously correct. If you take $g(x)=\delta(x-a)$ then it leads to the correct answer $f(x)\,=\,\exp\left[\int_{x_{0}}^{x}\delta(x^{\prime}-a)\,dx^{\prime}\right]$. However, the iterative method will generate integrations over products of distributions.